# how do you set a url routing routevalue to a hyperlink's navigate url property in an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

If the following routes:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Build",      // Route name
           "build",      // Route URL
           "~/build.aspx" // Web page to handle route
        );

     routes.MapPageRoute(
       "Type",      // Route name
       "build/{type}",      // Route URL
       "~/build.aspx" // Web page to handle route
    );

       routes.MapPageRoute(
       "Project",      // Route name
       "build/{type}/{project}",      // Route URL
       "~/build.aspx" // Web page to handle route
    );

 routes.MapPageRoute(
       "Task",      // Route name
       "task/{type}/{project}",      // Route URL
       "~/task.aspx" // Web page to handle route
    );
```

How do I set a hyperlinks navigate url in the .aspx (not code behind) to the route named 'task' where type = 'tool' and project = 'excel'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in a grid view template field:

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btnUp" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>'
        NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("Task",
          new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
          {
            {"type", "tool" },
            {"project" , "excel" }
          }) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

or, you can set parameters from data source:

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btnUp" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>'
        NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("Task",
          new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
          {
            {"type", Eval("Type") },
            {"project" , Eval("ProjectType") }
          }) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a **RouteName** param. E.g. you can set a route like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=Project, type=1, project=2%>">Type 2</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set route values like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnk3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:Name=IPhone,ID=1 %>" Text="IPhone" />
```

In Global.asax my configuration is like this

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute",
"BookStore/{Name}/{ID}",
"~/Webpages/BookStore/ViewBookDemo.aspx");
```

Comment: What if you have another route that uses Name and ID as params but is a different route than "bookstore/{name}/{id}" but is "hardwarestore/{name}/{id}" - how do you differentiate which route is to be used?